# How to delete the most recent git commit?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I can't believe I'm the first one to ask this, but my searching through git questions hasn't given me the precise answer I need, so:  I just made a commit on the master branch and I realize that it is buggy and won't be ready for prime time without alot of work, so I just want to get rid of it.  How do I do this?  `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git reset --hard sha-of-bad-commit` don't do anything except move the `HEAD` back to this bad commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the commit before the wrong commit.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  stack-o is not letting me accept your answer yet.  If I don't get around to it later, please feel free to remind me.

Comment: Or '--medium' or '--soft' if you don't want to loose the work you did in the workspace.

Comment: @Philippe: `--mixed` not `--medium` :-) it's also the default if you don't specify one of `--soft`, `--mixed`, `--hard`. Also, now you have me doing it, I almost typed soft/medium/hard. :-) (It would make sense!)